# How to relate between multi-color function in JSP with the bit datatype value retrieved from database MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, colors, background-color

Updated: 5/5/2015

Firstly, what I understand about bit datatype in SQL is that it will return value  1 or 0 and 'True' or 'False' only. And secondly, I learn how to change background and text color of elements in HTML from (http://www.javascripter.net/faq/changehtmlelementcolor.htm) which when I look its source code (Ctrl+U), I understand it using getElementById to get the element's color. However, I don't know how to relate this two different knowledge and use it in my JSP page.

Because I didn't get 10 reputation here, so it is hard to explain the situation without the pictures but I try my best.

There is this situation where I have a virtual table in my JSP page where it has column MONTH and the rows are the Application Name

There will be indicator where there are 4 color that assign for Heavily in used period(green), Data retrieved from other application/maintenance(blue), Involve system maintenance (brown), Not involve system maintenance (white/no color)

```html
<script language="javascript">
function setBgColorById(id,sColor) {
 var elem;
 if (document.getElementById) {
  if (elem=document.getElementById(id)) {
   if (elem.style) {
    elem.style.backgroundColor=sColor;
    return 1;  // success
   }
  }
 }
 return 0;  // failure
}
</script>

<!--Search form for Application name-->
<form name="frmParam" action="web2AppOverview.jsp" method="POST">
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblnoBorder">
  <tr align="left">
    <td><strong>App Name: </strong></td>
 <td><%renderDropDownList3(out, "reqContentID",  arrAppName,  requestValue.contentID ,"onchange=\"onParamChange()\"");%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input name="reqSearch" class="iform" type="submit" value="Search"></td>
</table>
</form> 

<!--The process to colour the cells in this virtual table start here, nothing to do with form search above-->

<!--Color Indicator-->
<br>
<table border="1">
 <tr><td width="20" height="10" id="elemw" href="#" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" onClick="setBgColorById('elem','#FFFFFF');return false;">
    </td>
    <td> Not involve system maintenance / display only / osolete system </td></tr>
    <tr><td width="20" height="10" id="elembr" href="#" style="background-color:#CCCC99;" onClick="setBgColorById('elem','#CCCC99');return false;">
    </td>
    <td> Involve system maintenance </td></tr>
    <tr><td width="20" height="10" id="elembl" href="#" style="background-color:#7994FF;" onClick="setBgColorById('elem','#7994FF');return false;">
    </td>
    <td> Data retrieved from other application/maintenance </td></tr>
    <tr><td width="20" height="10" id="elemg" href="#" style="background-color:#009933;" onClick="setBgColorById('elem','#009933');return false;">
    </td>
    <td> Heavily in used period </td></tr>
</table>
<br>
  
<!--Situation: to colour the cells in this Virtual table for Column Application Name & Month-->

<!--Column Developer (application developer name) is example how I use the codes inside the table and where I pass the value to process jsp page to manipulate data (add/delete) and nothing to do with the search form above or column Month-->

<table width="100%" align="center" class="normal" border="1">  
  <tr class="normalTbl-subheader">
    <td width="3%" rowspan="2" align="center"><strong>No</strong></td>
    <td width="10%" rowspan="2" align="center"><strong>App Name</strong></td>
    <td colspan="12" align="center"><strong>Month</strong></td>
    <td width="9%" rowspan="2" align="center"><strong>Developer</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="normalTbl-subheader">
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Jan</strong></td> 
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Feb</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Mar</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Apr</strong></td> 
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Mei</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Jun</strong></td> 
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Jul</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Aug</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Sept</strong></td> 
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Oct</strong></td>
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Nov</strong></td> 
    <td width="3%" align="center"><strong>Dec</strong></td>
</tr> 
  
  <!--don't ask me about Timeline and rowCount cause I guess its not related with the months. Timeline is where I retrieve data from DB for search form-->
  
  <%if(!requestValue.strSearch.equals("")){
 if(arrTimeline.size() > 0){
  for (int rowCount=0; rowCount < arrTimeline.size(); rowCount++) { 
   Timeline timeline  = (Timeline) arrTimeline.get(rowCount);
   
%>
<!--contentID is ID for Application Name-->
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top"><%=rowCount+1%></td>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><%=timeline.strAppName%></td>
    <input type="hidden" id="contentID<%=rowCount%>" name="contentID<%=rowCount%>" value="<%=timeline.contentID%>">
    
      <%/***MONTHS****/
   ConnIntranet = cnHR();
   String act = getParam(request,"act").trim();
   try{
     String jan="",feb="",mar="",apr="",may="",jun="",jul="",aug="",sept="",oct="",nov="",dec="";
  String white="", brown="", blue="", green="";
  String sqlMonths = " SELECT DISTINCT fjan, ffeb, fmar, fapr, " 
                     + " fmay, fjun, fjul, faug, fsept, foct, fnov, fdec" 
                     + " FROM intAppOverview " 
                     + " WHERE intcontentsID = " 
                     + toSQL(timeline.contentID,TextTYPE)+
      " AND fdevid IS NULL";
     //out.print(sqlMonths);
  %>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>

        <!--UNTIL HERE, I LOST-->

        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" id="elem"></td>
  <%}catch(Exception e) {out.print(e);}%> 
                 
    
                  
     <% /***DEVELOPER****/%>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
        <p>
     <% try{
            String devId = "";
   ResultSet rs=null;
   String sql = " SELECT fstaffid, fstaffname FROM hrconfirm" +
      " WHERE fstaffid <>'' AND fstatus <> 'Part Time' " +
      " AND fEstatus='Y'"+
      " AND fdept = 'SODEMC' ORDER BY fstaffname";
      PreparedStatement stmt = ConnIntranet.prepareStatement(sql);
      synchronized(stmt){
   rs = stmt.executeQuery();} 
 %>
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="<%=act%>">
    <select class="iform" id = "devId<%=rowCount%>" name="devId<%=rowCount%>" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <%   while(rs.next()){
    devId = getValue(rs,"fstaffid");
    if(devId.equals("")){%>
    <option value="<%=devId%>" selected><%=getValue(rs,"fstaffname").trim()%></option>
    <%    }else { %> 
    <option value="<%=devId%>"><%=getValue(rs,"fstaffname").trim()%></option>
    <%    }
   }stmt.close();%>
    </select>
    <% out.print("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"addDevName(" + "contentID" + rowCount + " ,devId" + rowCount + ");\">Add</a>");
    }catch (Exception e) {out.print(e);}%>
    </p>
    <p>   
    <% try{
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String sql = " SELECT i.fdevid, i.fdevname FROM intAppOverview i "+
        " INNER JOIN hrconfirm h "+
        " ON i.fdevid = h.fstaffid"+
        " WHERE h.fdept = 'SODEMC'"+
        " AND i.intcontentsID = "+ toSQL(timeline.contentID,TextTYPE);
    PreparedStatement stmt = ConnIntranet.prepareStatement(sql);
    synchronized(stmt){
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();} 
    while(rs.next()){
      String devId  = getValue(rs,"fdevid").trim();
      String devName  = getValue(rs,"fdevname").trim();
  %>     <%=devName%> 
  <%  out.print(" | <a href=\"web2AppOverview_process.jsp?act=delDevName"+"&contentID="+timeline.contentID+"&devId="+devId+"\" onClick=\"return confirmDel()\">Del</a>");
  }stmt.close();
 }catch (Exception e) {out.print(e);}%>
    </p>
      </td>
</tr> 
      
<%   
  } //for()
 }else{
%>
<tr>
   <td colspan="20" align="center" class="red">No record found!</td>  
</tr>   
<% } // else -- if(arrStudent.size() > 0){%>           
<% }  //  if form submitted %>             
</table>
```

In the database, I got table intAppOverview where the months (Jan, Feb, Mar,..., Dec) assigned to bit datatype.

When I try to retrieve the data by using String sql = "SELECT jan, feb.... FROM intAppOverview", its only shows 1, 0 and empty(for null values) in the virtual table on the JSP page.

My question is: how do I relate this 2 conditions to get 1 color for a cell and it work for every cells.

For example: column 'May' that laps with the Application Name 'Student Miscellaneous' have 'green' color and the value is 1/'True'. Meanwhile, other cell with white/no color will be null or 0/'False' value.

You may run the code above and click on the color indicator to see how it work so far.

Thank you for your time to read and reply this. >.<

Regards,
Eja

Comment: Why don't you post what code you have so far to help people understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, actually my coding far more complicated than what I explained above, since i try to use the very simple example, so I made a situation that almost the same as my coding for better understanding but I don't have the coding for situation above and I don't know how to explain my complicated coding even I can post it here. Never mind, let me try to post the codes with the explaination. Thanks for let me know, @Shaggy. ;)

Comment: @Shaggy Well, I changed the database table intAppOverview columns datatype for month as int & I guess i had found a way to do it now. while about the coloring cells, I do it like this:
<script language="javascript">
function clickme(obj){  
if (obj.style.backgroundColor =='rgb(255, 255, 255)' || obj.style.backgroundColor == "") {
obj.style.backgroundColor ='#CCCC99';
}else if (obj.style.backgroundColor == 'rgb(204, 204, 153)' ){
obj.style.backgroundColor  = '#7994FF';}}</script>

 <td align="center" valign="top" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)" onclick="javascript:clickme(this)"></td>

Comment: I wasn't sure how your were trying to pull off a 4 color change with a bit value so changing it to int is probably the way to go.  Why don't you post what you did as an answer to this question and include the code above.  You can then check your answer as accepted and other users will know what you did.

Comment: Will do @Shaggy but right now I am try to figure out how to relate the value in db with the color since I need to store the value that assign to the color, such as 0 is for white color. Once I'm done, I will share the answer. ;)